# My sqlite query(update) looks not working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I want to update one of the record in sqlite table like this at once.

travellName : self.savedName -> self.editedName

currency : self.savedCurrency -> self.editedCurrency

Rate : self.savedRate -> self.editedRate

startBudget : self.savedBudget -> self.editedBudget

leftAssets : self.savedLeftAssets -> self.editedLeftAssets

enter code here

```
NSString *qsql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE Travell SET travellName = 
'%@' and currency = '%@' and changeRate = '%@' and startBudget = '%@' and 
leftBudget = '%@' WHERE travellName = '%@' and currency = '%@' and changeRate =
'%@' and startBudget ='%@' and leftBudget = '%@'", self.editedName,   
self.editedCurrency, self.editedRate,self.editedBudget, self.editedLeftAssets, 
self.savedName, self.savedCurrency, self.savedRate, self.savedBudget, 
self.savedLeftAssets];

if(sqlite3_exec(db, [qsql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) != SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_close(db);
        NSLog(@"Failed to update leftBudget");
}
else{
        NSLog(@"Success to update leftBudget");
}
```

It is my code. I have lots of field to update at once. is there any fault at query??

I've checked all of the value of variable and there were no problem.
Weird, sqlite3_exec(...) returns SQLITE_OK and NSLog(@"Success to update leftBudget") was executed. but the problem is updating table wasn't executed properly..
I have no idea as program says SQLITE_OK but table wasn't update properly..

Comment: You should delimit the columns to be updated with a comma not AND.  E.g.  UPDATE Travell SET travellName = '%@', currency = '%@', etc.

Comment: thanks very much, John. you r right. what a shame...

Answer (score 1):

In the UPDATE statement, multiple columns to be set must be separated not with AND but with commas.

`SET travellName = '...' and currency = '...' and ...` is interpreted as setting the single column `travellName` to the value of the expression `'...' and currency = '...' and ...`, in which AND is a boolean operator; the final value of this expression is either 0 or 1.

(And this will blow up when the travel name contains a quote. You should use [sqlite3_mprintf](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/mprintf.html) to format the strings correctly.)